# Не находит таблицу или не вводит в её значение

Tags: sql, база-данных, discord, sqlite3, discord.py

Не находит таблицу или не вводит в её значение

```
def add(self, table: str = None, column: str = None, value: int = None) -> bool:
    """Увеличить значение в БД"""
    if table is None or column is None or value is None:
        raise TypeError('Параметры в add должны быть настроены')

    if not isinstance(value, int):
        raise TypeError('Значение для добавления должно быть числом')

    query = f"{table}_{column}"
    self.db.execute("SELECT value FROM json WHERE id = ?", [query])
    result = self.db.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        self.db.execute("INSERT INTO json (id, value) VALUES (?, ?)", [query, value])
        self.sqlite.commit()
    else:
        try:
            current_value = int(result[0])
            new_value = current_value + value
            self.db.execute("UPDATE json SET value = ? WHERE id = ?", [str(new_value), query])
            self.sqlite.commit()
        except ValueError:
            raise TypeError('Текущее значение столбца не число для добавления к нему')
    return True
```

Что же делать я незнаю

Comment: А как выглядит таблица и какую ошибку вы получаете?

Comment: Таблица в Sqlite или внешнее использование?

Comment: В sqlite. Но если есть возможность продемонстрировать внешнее использование, то это тоже может быть полезно